# 304 Not Modified when loading images from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, browser-cache, http-status-codes

On my page I have the following JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$("#my-div").append($("<img>", {src: "/api/userimage/"+imageHash}));
```

It works fine when the server returns `200 OK` for the image but not when it returns `304 Not Modified`. In the latter case the browser just displays a "broken image" placeholder.

How do I make it so the browser gets the image from cache in case of 304? I don't want to use tricks to bypass the cache, as caching of unchanged images is exactly what I want.

The server also returns 304 for other resources (.js and .css files). Those work fine since they are sourced directly from static HTML markup, not from JavaScript. I'm using HTTPS, if it matters.

I can provide more details if the solution is not obvious from the above description.

Comment: I tried to reproduce but I don't see any broken image with an image that is cached for 10 minutes then server replies with a 304 not modified : https://jsfiddle.net/BenChe/8vwt0ggL/2/ Can you be more specific ? Have you tested on all browser you can have ? Can you build a jsfiddle example and give the url to the images you try to insert ?

Comment: It is happening to me on Safari. I have my image on cache but when I ask for it again, it generates other request with: Status: 304 Not Modified
Source: Memory CacheAddress:
Initiator: jquery-3.2.1.min-9a4f93d587a6afebcf49d97281290a53.js:1938:349